# in R, Populate an empty column with strings based on matching string from another dataframe present across multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr, data-cleaning, string-matching

I do not think that this question has been asked yet.
Basically I have the following dataframes df1 and df2, I want to populate a column on df1, df1$LOC_numbers, from values on a column in df2, df2$Symbol, the criteria for populating df1 column is that the strings in df1$Orthologue_GeneSymbol is identical to any string in the same row across any column in df2. Based on that then the value from df2$Symbol can be used to populate df1$LOC_numbers.

Here there are the sample dataframes:

df1:

'''

```
    FBgn_ID   GeneSymbol Ortholog_FBgn_ID Ortholog_GeneSymbol LOC_numbers
6    FBgn0000008            a      FBgn0114341             GG22167          NA
18   FBgn0000014        abd-A      FBgn0109040             GG16810          NA
30   FBgn0000015        Abd-B      FBgn0109036             GG16806          NA
42   FBgn0000017          Abl      FBgn0108099             GG15861          NA
53   FBgn0000018          abo      FBgn0102648             GG10339          NA
```

'''

df2:

'''

```
     Symbol       X        X.1        X.2         X.3         X.4         X.5         X.6
1   LOC6540581     Adh     Adh-PA    GG25120   Dere\\Adh  GG25120-PA        <NA>        <NA>
2   LOC6541346     eve     CG2328     eve-PA     GG24126   Dere\\eve   CG2328-PA  GG24126-PA
3   LOC6548272     amy      Amy-p    GG22216    Amy-p-PA Dere\\Amy-p  GG22216-PA        <NA>
4   LOC6548270     amy      Amy-d    GG20663    Amy-d-PA Dere\\Amy-d  GG20663-PA        <NA>
5   LOC6553738      ry        Xdh     Xdh-PA     GG19379   Dere\\Xdh  GG19379-PA        <NA>
```

'''

I could do it if the string matching is based only on one column, but I am not really sure how to proceed if I have to look across multiple columns. obviously both these dataframes are much longer (around 14k rows)

here is what I have tried for one column only

'''

```
df1$LOC_numbers = sapply(1:nrow(df1),function(x){
  ifelse(df1$Ortholog_GeneSymbol[x] %in% df2$X,
         df2$X[grep(df1$Ortholog_GeneSymbol[x],df2$X)],
         NA)
})
```

'''

Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: Do you think you can present sample data that actually present matches? There is nothing in common between these two. My proposal is to reshape `df2` (`pivot_longer`) and the left-join onto `df1`. Simple enough, but it's hard to know for sure since nothing matches.

Comment: please always share code for your data instead of only the formated tables. You can use `dput(df)` and `dput(df2)`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a pivot/join/coalesce methodology.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_longer
pivot_longer(df2, -Symbol, values_to = "Ortholog_GeneSymbol") %>%
  select(LOC_numbers.y = Symbol, Ortholog_GeneSymbol) %>%
  left_join(df1, ., by = "Ortholog_GeneSymbol") %>%
  mutate(LOC_numbers = coalesce(LOC_numbers.y, LOC_numbers)) %>%
  select(-LOC_numbers.y)
#       FBgn_ID GeneSymbol Ortholog_FBgn_ID Ortholog_GeneSymbol LOC_numbers
# 1 FBgn0000008          a      FBgn0114341             GG22167        <NA>
# 2 FBgn0000014      abd-A      FBgn0109040             GG16810        <NA>
# 3 FBgn0000015      Abd-B      FBgn0109036             GG16806        <NA>
# 4 FBgn0000017        Abl      FBgn0108099             GG15861        <NA>
# 5 FBgn0000018        abo      FBgn0102648             GG10339        <NA>
```

It produces nothing here since the sample data has no intersection. If I fake your data, we can see it partially in action:

```r
df1[1:2,4] <- df2$X.5[3:4]
pivot_longer(df2, -Symbol, values_to = "Ortholog_GeneSymbol") %>%
  select(LOC_numbers.y = Symbol, Ortholog_GeneSymbol) %>%
  left_join(df1, ., by = "Ortholog_GeneSymbol") %>%
  mutate(LOC_numbers = coalesce(LOC_numbers.y, LOC_numbers)) %>%
  select(-LOC_numbers.y)
#       FBgn_ID GeneSymbol Ortholog_FBgn_ID Ortholog_GeneSymbol LOC_numbers
# 1 FBgn0000008          a      FBgn0114341          GG22216-PA  LOC6548272
# 2 FBgn0000014      abd-A      FBgn0109040          GG20663-PA  LOC6548270
# 3 FBgn0000015      Abd-B      FBgn0109036             GG16806        <NA>
# 4 FBgn0000017        Abl      FBgn0108099             GG15861        <NA>
# 5 FBgn0000018        abo      FBgn0102648             GG10339        <NA>
```

Notes:

- I prefer `left_join` here solely to keep the `df1` variables on the left, it's purely aesthetic. `right_join` (and subsequent reordering if needed) works just as well.
- I explicitly named the `df2` pivoted column `LOC_numbers.y` to be clear that it would be joined and a distinct column from what already exists. I could have named it `ZZZ` for the same effect, but it's just declarative and a little clearer the *intent* of where it should join.
- I *suspect* that your existing `LOC_numbers` is all `NA`, just a place-holder column. If that's the case, then I suggest a better way is to avoid the coalescing altogether and just join it in:

  ```r
  df1$LOC_numbers <- NULL
  pivot_longer(df2, -Symbol, values_to = "Ortholog_GeneSymbol") %>%
    select(LOC_numbers = Symbol, Ortholog_GeneSymbol) %>%
    left_join(df1, ., by = "Ortholog_GeneSymbol")
  ```

  Notice the change to `LOC_numbers` directly, and no need to `mutate`/`select` at the end.